# What does the inequality stand?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

The additive $p-$ adic valuation of $\mathbb{Q}_p$:

$$w_p: \left\{\begin{matrix}
\mathbb{Q}_p \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\}\\ 
p^m u \mapsto m\\ 
0 \mapsto \infty
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q}: w_p(x+y) \geq \min \{ w_p(x), w_p(y)\}$$

If $w_p(x) \neq w_p(y)$, then the equality stands.

This is the proof, according to my notes:

$$x=p^m u_1 | u_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$$

$$y=p^n u^2 | u_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$$

$$m,n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Without loss of generality, we suppose that $m \leq n$.

$$x+y=p^m(u_1+p^{n-m}u_2)$$

$$w_p(x+y) \geq m$$

If $n>m$, then $u_1+p^{n-m}u_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$

In this case:

$$w_p(x+y)=m=\min \{ w_p(x), w_p(y) \}$$

If $n=m$, $\displaystyle{ w_p(x+y) \geq n=m=\min \{ w_p(x), w_p(y)\} }$

Could you explain me why it is : $w_p(x+y) \geq m$ and not $w_p(x+y)=m$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** e.g. $3^2|(2+3^0\cdot7)$. So when $m= n$...

---

Expanding a bit more based on the comment below, when $m=n$, you have $x+y = p^m(u_1+u_2)$.  Now you could have the case where $w_p(u_1+u_2) > 0$ even though $w_p(u_i)=0$, as in the example above.  For another e.g. note $w_2(2+2) = 2 \ge w_p(2)=1$.

Comment: This is a good example, but I wish you had written a few more words.

Comment: I understand!!! Thanks a lot!!!